# How to properly handle Excepcion when creating new record in db throught Service-Repository pattern. [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use Service-Repository pattern for the first time in my Laravel app and I have to handle a situation: a record can´t be added to a table (for example because trying to add same unique email....).

I have `CustomAuthCOntroller` with `customRegistration` method:

```php
//Validatting request
$request->validated();

//running logic behind this in service
$is_Registered = $this->loginService->register_user(
    $request->get('email'),
    $request->get('password'),
    $request->get('name'),
    $request->get('surname')
);

// If everything goes right shol login page
if ($is_Registered) {
    return redirect("/login")->withSuccess('Registrácia prebehla úspešne');
} else {
    // Else HERE I HAVE TO SHOW what error happened 
    return redirect("/register")->withError('Registrácia prebehla úspešne');
}
```

My `LoginService->register_user`:

```php
public function register_user($email, $password, $firstname, $lastname, $role = 'student') {
    $user_attributes = [
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $password,
        'name' => $firstname,
        'surname' => $lastname,
    ];

    $this->userRepositor->create_new_user($user_attributes);
}
```

And my `userRepository->create_new_user`:

```php
public function create_new_user(Array $attributes) : bool
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    
    try {
        User::create($attributes);

        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
    }
}
```

Is this right way how to achieve my goal? How can I show the error in my view if a exception is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have any problems as you should be validating your input, so if the email/username or whatever that should be unique does already exist, then the validation should fail and return automatically with the errors (no `try/catch`).

If, you still want to catch any other possible error, let's say the DB timed out because of a connection problem or whatever (something not related to data), then you could either have a general `try/catch` (as I will show you) or do not catch it at all and let it go to the user, but this last approach depends a lot in your frontend:

- If you have an API, then JS should handle this and show the error correctly.
- If this is not an API (no AJAX), then the error could be shown to the user as a `500` error (0% descriptive for the user and would be a blank page with a `500` on it).

So, if you want the `try/catch` approach, you could do this:

```php
//Validatting request
$request->validated();

try {
    //running logic behind this in service
    $this->loginService->register_user(
        $request->get('email'),
        $request->get('password'),
        $request->get('name'),
        $request->get('surname')
    );

    // If everything goes right shol login page
    return redirect("/login")->withSuccess('Registrácia prebehla úspešne');
} catch (Throwable $exception) {
    // HERE I HAVE TO SHOW what error happened
    // You can even add the exception error with $exception->getMessage()
    return redirect("/register")->withError('Registrácia prebehla úspešne');
}
```

And then, change your `create_new_user` to either of these:

```php
public function create_new_user(Array $attributes) : bool
{
    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {
        User::create($attributes);

        DB::commit();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();

        throw $e;
    }
}
```

Or use [`DB::transaction()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions). It will automatically *rollback* and *throw* the exception. See the source code [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/dc0f21664cabe48c1183d909f3d9d31cd5d69673/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php#L20-L65) and [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/dc0f21664cabe48c1183d909f3d9d31cd5d69673/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php#L77-L104).

```php
public function create_new_user(Array $attributes) : bool
{
    DB::transaction(function () use ($attributes) {
        User::create($attributes);
    });
}
```

---

One personal recommendatation, do not declare methods as `kebab_case` like `create_new_user`, follow the PSR standard and Laravel standard, it should be `camelCase`: `createNewUser`.